# COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to execute following sql query from php, it is not returning result set object, instead returns `boolean`. when I remove collate from sql then it returns result set. Is there any problem with php / mysql libraries which are using. mysql 8 version I am using.

```
SELECT  if('f' is null ,'f' ,'t') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci as result from dummy
```

Comment: What is the database layout? How do you get the result (php code please)?

Comment: To fetch result using below php : mysqli_query(Connection, SQL Query);. I have checked error no, error : 1253 : COLLATION 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'. Any idea what change I need to do from php ? Same SQL is executing successfully from my sql command.

Comment: I have also verified in my sql -> show variables like '%char%' and result shows utf8mb4_unicode_ci for all variables other than character_set_system variable, which is utf8